# Spring in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition does not bind @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have seen issues regarding the paid version as well, but couldn't find a solution. IDEA CE complains about a missing bean that should be defined.

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'domain.service.KitchenService' in your configuration.
```

But in my controller, I do have it:

```
@Autowired
private KitchenService service;
```

The majority of the solutions I found weren't clear and the only clear one was to annotate the starting point class with the 3 annotations `@SpringBootApplication` has, but made no difference.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

*First of all, Intellij IDEA is not a free IDE. For high-scale development and framework support, you need to buy Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition to get all the support.*

**In free edition, they don't provide Spring support.**

**Recommendation for free IDE :** The best free IDE is *Spring Tools Suite.* Pivotal team has specially designed the Eclipse IDE for Spring Framework support and it's far better than any other IDE.

And Pivotal also recommends to use this IDE.

The reason for why the `KitchenService` bean is not created are as follows :

1. Either `@Service` annotation is missing on `KitchenService`.
2. Or you have missed to add the package in `@ComponentScan` where `KitchenService` is present.

*Therefore,* `KitchenService` *bean is missing and Spring is not able to find the bean when you are autowiring it.*

Please verify the issue based on these reasons.

Comment: I don't think so because it works on any other IDE. Eclipse and VSCode. On IDEA, I can start the server, but if I save a file being autowired somewhere, the error is thrown. Only on IDEA.

Comment: @gamofe share your code so that I can pin point your mistake.

Comment: @gamofe Moreover, Intellij Community Edition doesn't support spring. How are you running then ?

Comment: Community does not have the support the paid version has, but it is still Java and IDEA is for Java programming. It should do all the basic stuff as autocompletion, etc. It's the same thing with basic Eclipse. You do not need the plugin they offer because it still works, still autocompletes, it just doesn't have the facilities the plugin offers such as editing starter and so on.

Comment: Also, I had already used IDEA CE with Kotlin and things worked normally, but never had attempted with Java. I don't know what's the issue with Java and it can't be issue with the CE edition. Many people had similar - if not the same - issues with the paid version. This is on IDEA. With CE, what I remember not having is creating a new project from the IDE and not having support for the `application.properties` file. Things we do not actually NEED.

Comment: Well, now, if it really is because it's not the paid version, it means they sabotaged it to not work properly because with Eclipse without STS it works at it should and VSCode too, even the same project I mention to have issues on IDEA CE. And if that's the case I refuse to buy anything from them. But again, I don't believe this is the reason. Anyways, thank you for you help but I will stick with Eclipse until a solution comes out, that is not buying the paid version since it also had issues as I've seen.